# Getting Menu Details in Google Places

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I'm trying to access the menu items of restaurants and read on a post a couple of months ago that this is not available. Are there any plans to introduce an endpoint to allow the querying to menu items in places details api?

Comment: Currently, menus can be viewed through the Google Maps App but not through the Web

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.